# calculating number of inversions in a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

how do we get calculate inversions in a list in Haskell?
 eg. `[1, 2, 3, 1]` , `xi > xj` where `i < j` is the condition for inversion. In the given example it would be 3.

I tried the following code:

```
module Inversion where

inv :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
inv [] = []
inv xs = [(a, b) | a <- xs, b <- tail xs, a > b]
```

I even tried to zip it with tail and then get the pairs.

Comment: Either I'm way to tired, or the list should have only two inversions: [1, 2, 3, 1] has only two: (3, 1)  and (2, 1).

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.List

inv :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
inv xs = [(a,b) | (a:bs) <- tails xs, b <- bs, a > b]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive implementation close to what you already got:

```
inv :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
inv [] = []
inv xs = [(a, b) | b <- xs', a > b] ++ inv xs'
    where xs' = tail xs
          a = head xs
```

It does the first thing that comes to mind: compare the first element with every other element in the list and then do the same with the rest of the list.

Your example:

```
*Main> inv [1,2,3,1]
[(2,1),(3,1)]
```

Comment: Definitely better to read than using `mapMaybe`. I shouldn't shun list comprehensions so easily.

Comment: always depends on preferences - there is nothing wrong with using all your tools ;) - I just don't know them all :D (for example never used `mapMaybe` before so your answer provides value for me ;) )

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
inv lst = filter nonOrdPair $ zip lst (tail lst)
        where nonOrdPair (a,b) = a > b
```

on your example gives

```
Prelude> inv [1, 2, 3, 1]
[(3,1)]
```

if you only need the first element you can get it with `map fst`.

Comment: You're missing the second inversion, (2, 1).

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the question then, I thought we were only looking for consecutive out of order elements (since the question said that `3` is the answer for the example).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `zip` and `tail` in this case. This would lead to only comparing *consecutive pairs* where you need *all pairs*. So given a list `(x:xs)`, you need to check whether any of the `xs` is smaller than `x`:

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

checkInv :: Ord a => a -> a -> Maybe (a,a)
checkInv x y = if x <= y then Nothing
                         else Just (x, y)

inv :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,a)]    
inv []     = []
inv (x:xs) = mapMaybe (checkInv x) xs ++ inv xs
```

```
> inv [1,2,3,1]
[(2,1), (3,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw some folds into the matter:

```
inv :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,a)]
inv [x] = [] :: [(x,x)]
inv xs = foldl (\acc x -> if (head xs) > x then (head xs, x) : acc else acc) [] xs
```

Zipping and then filtering the pairs is not a bad idea, but you have to consider all the pairs for that to work:

```
inv xs = filter (\(a, b) -> a > b) $ allPairs xs
  where
    allPairs xs = allPairsHelp xs (tail xs)
      where
        allPairsHelp xs [] = []
        allPairsHelp xs ys = zip xs ys ++ allPairsHelp xs (tail ys)
```